# What is the best OAuth2 C# library?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, .net-3.5, oauth

It seems like many app providers are using OAuth2 to allow API access, such as Twitter and Facebook. Does anyone use a good library to do OAuth2 processing that is general enough to use across all applications?

Comment: I'm confused by the vote to close. Asking for library recommendations to accomplish a specific task is now "subjective and argumentative"?

Comment: Some people for some reason think that any idea of "best" and "worst" is completely non-objective.  I have no idea why, but they think "green is the best color!!!!" is the same as "what is the best library given these conditions:  ..."

Comment: There is also the Microsoft implementation based in Katana, https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth

Comment: I think there's an internal policy for all SO moderators to close "recommendation" questions b/c they're afraid to get google penalty for "thin content"

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I didn't look into it's internals (source code link is broken), but in general [DotNetOpenAuth](http://www.dotnetopenauth.net/) seems to be quite professional.

Update: OAuth 2 and OpenID are now supported as well.

Comment: Last I checked DotNetOpenAuth didn't support OAuth 2.0.

Comment: @Micah you are right. I believe something was not paid attention to when I answered (maybe their design was different or they erroneously claimed OAUth2 support). I'll update the answer now.

Comment: Now (Febuary 2013) DotNetOpenAuth supports OAuth2 and OpenID.

Comment: @GrzegorzGierlik Thank you for the update. As people rarely read comments, I've put an update instead of your modification.

Comment: As I understood, it can't be used for commercial projects. I installed this library from NuGet and it asked me about license for Microsoft libraries (Microsoft.Bcl.dll and two others). Here is license https://www.microsoft.com/net/dotnet_library_license.htm with text "You may not use the software for commercial software hosting services." Please, correct me if I'm wrong

Comment: @white.zaz I am not the developer of that library so I can only guess. The homepage states "It’s completely free to use on personal and commercial projects" . I think the best approach would be to contact the author of the library and ask explicitly.

Comment: I highly not recommend using DNOA. There is almost no documentation on how to use the library so you will definitely be on your own whenever you face any issues. If the web service you are trying to access has a .NET SDK which includes an OAuth implementation then go for that. A personal advice for which I payed a high price, don't go for DNOA otherwise get ready  to have restless nights reading through the code alone!

Comment: [Source code link](https://github.com/DotNetOpenAuth/DotNetOpenAuth) isn't broken anymore.

Comment: What about the `IdentityServer4`?

Answer (score 22):

You should look on [OAuth2](https://github.com/titarenko/OAuth2). It is .NET implementation of OAuth 1.0 and OAuth 2.0 protocol for most of the popular providers:

- google
- facebook
- twitter
- foursquare
- instagram
- linked-in
- windows live
- vkontakte
- odnoklassniki
- yandex
- mail.ru
- github

Nuget package is [there](http://nuget.org/packages/OAuth2).

Comment: Do we have any detailed working example of this library ? I can see some usage examples showed but I am not understanding like what is AuthroizationRoot

Answer (score 7):

I haven't seen any good frameworks out there yet for OAuth2.  I've decided to try and roll my own for a project.

My framework so far supports bearer tokens and all of the oauth 2 flows (challenge/response, implicit, client credential, resource owner password, and refresh token).

It's a little clunky, and I'm working on my first REST service built on this framework.

Check it out, any feedback or contributions would be appreciated.

https://github.com/ghorsey/SharpOAuth2

Answer (score 1):

I would look at the [Hammock](http://hammock.codeplex.com/) REST client library.  It is general purpose REST client, but it provides OAuth support as well.

Comment: Hammock REST doesn't support oAuth2. Only oAuth 1.0a